# SQL query regex

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex

I have TableA with ColumnA. ColumnA is VARCHAR that contains values like:

```
#1002#15#
#1002#16#
#1003#17#
#1003#17#16#
#1004#18#
#1004#18#3#
#1004#18#3#1155#
```

I need to find repeating numbers in ColumnA, .e.g:

```
#1002#15#1002#
#1004#18#3#1004#
#1003#17#17#
```

I tried number of LIKE patterns as described here:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187489(v=sql.105).aspx

to no avail so far primarily because those repeating digits can be 2-5 chars long..

Comment: Sql server does not support regular expressions outside of a CRL function. You better normalize your database and change that columnA to a table instead of [keeping delimited data in a single column.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad)

Comment: ugh. thank you. the problem is that I'm not owning the structure of the table, so, I need to query what I have in there...cannot change the structure. hm. so, you're essentially saying there is no good way of doing it in SQL server. perhaps I can dump it out to a separate table because it's one time exercise of finding dup numeric values there...

Comment: You can use  iTVF splitter function, it's fast. See detailes http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/
If you have no CREATE permissions, just use it as cte

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since normalizing the database is impossible in your case, you need a different approach.
One option is to use [`CROSS APPLY`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156(v=sql.105).aspx) to a [string splitting function](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings) that will take the content of your column and split it to rows, thus enabling you to to query the content of the column.

For this demonstration I've chosen the `SplitStrings_XML` from Aaron's article:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.SplitStrings_XML
(
   @List       NVARCHAR(MAX),
   @Delimiter  NVARCHAR(255)
)
RETURNS TABLE
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
   RETURN 
   (  
      SELECT Item = y.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'nvarchar(4000)')
      FROM 
      ( 
        SELECT x = CONVERT(XML, '<i>' 
          + REPLACE(@List, @Delimiter, '</i><i>') 
          + '</i>').query('.')
      ) AS a CROSS APPLY x.nodes('i') AS y(i)
   );
GO
```

Now, create and populate the sample table:

```
DECLARE @TableA as table
(
    id int identity(1,1),
    ColumnA varchar(100)
)

INSERT INTO @TableA VALUES
('#1002#15#'),
('#1002#16#'),
('#1003#17#'),
('#1003#17#16#'),
('#1004#18#'),
('#1004#18#3#'),
('#1004#18#3#1155#'),
('#1002#15#1002#'),
('#1004#18#3#1004#'),
('#1003#17#17#')
```

**That makes the query quite simple:**

```
SELECT id, ColumnA
FROM @TableA 
CROSS APPLY dbo.SplitStrings_XML(ColumnA, '#')
WHERE Item IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY id, ColumnA
HAVING COUNT(Item) > COUNT(DISTINCT Item)
```

**Results:**

```
id          ColumnA
----------- -----------------
8           #1002#15#1002#
9           #1004#18#3#1004#
10          #1003#17#17#
```